# Creating new rows from the elements in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has two fields, name and alias. If one or more aliases appear, I must create a new row for each alias and replace the name field with the alias field. I have something like the first table and it should look like the second table using pandas in python. thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to add rows to get all possible names and aliases as rows.

You could get all unique names as `set` and `reindex`:

```
out = (
 df.set_index('name')
   .reindex(set(df['name']).union(*df['alias']))
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
      name             alias
0     Juan  [Perez, Juancho]
1    Perez               NaN
2  Juancho               NaN
```

Or transform "alias" to a renamed DataFrame and `concat`:

```
out = (
 pd.concat([df,
            df['alias'].explode().rename('name').to_frame() 
          ])
   .sort_index(kind='stable')
)
```

Output:

```
      name             alias
0     Juan  [Perez, Juancho]
0    Perez               NaN
0  Juancho               NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Juan'],
                   'alias': [['Perez', 'Juancho']]})
```